# Insert substring if found

Tags: python, string

I'm given a string `my_str` in Python. What I want to do is: If `my_str` contains a substring `str1`, then insert a string `str2` right after the substring `str1` (and leave the rest of `my_str` intact.) Otherwise, do nothing. (Let's say that `my_str` contains no more than one substring being `str1`.)

The way I'm thinking is: Do a for-loop to find whether `str1` exists within `my_str`

```
for i in range(0, len(my_str)-len(str1)):
  if my_str[i:i+len(str1)] == str1:
    my_str = my_str[0:i] + str2 + my_str[i:]
```

I'm curious whether there's any magic way that can do this shorter.

Comment: Don't name a variable `str` or `file` or `dict` or `set` or `list`, etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest method is with `str.replace()`:

```
>>> str1 = "blah"
>>> str2 = "new"
>>> "testblah".replace(str1, str1+str2)
'testblahnew'
>>> "testblahtest".replace(str1, str1+str2)
'testblahnewtest'
>>> "test".replace(str1, str1+str2)
'test'
>>> "blahtestblah".replace(str1, str1+str2)
'blahnewtestblahnew'
```

We simply replace the original value with the new string appended to itself, essentially slotting in the new value.

A [quick tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) on replace() for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
def myReplace(myStr, str1, str2):
    try:
        i = myStr.index(str1)
        answer = myStr[:i+len(str1)] + str2 + myStr[i+len(str1):]
        return answer
    except ValueError:
        return myStr
```

Hope this helps

Comment: honest question- what is the advantage of doing it this way rather than using the built-in replace method?

Comment: @Anov: the built-in replace is what I would normally go with. Since the OP seems to be a beginner, I gave an answer that's closer to what he was trying to implement. I would have the `replace` way of doing this in my answer to be complete, but as I finished writing this solution, I noticed that someone else had posted that already.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget In think you used the try-except to handle `ValueError`, if that's the case then use `str.find()`, it returns -1 if the substring is not found.

Comment: The OP's version will replace every instance of `str1` with `str1+str2`; yours will only replace the first. The OP said "Let's say that my_str contains no more than one substring being str1", but it's worth pointing out the difference. With `replace`, you can do it either way—pass `1` for `count`, or don't. You could also do the same with this solution by adding a loop and passing `i+1` as the `start` to each `index`/`find` call.